# Equivalence of Dirac matrix representations

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I'm currently having fun with the Dirac matrices $\gamma^\mu$ which appear in the relativistic Fermion field equation (aka the Dirac equation). They need to satisfy the anticommutation relation
$$
\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}
$$
in order for the Dirac equation ($i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi=0$ to provide the correct relativistic energy-momentum expression.

Famously, the $\gamma^\mu$ must be at least 4-dimensional matrices, in order to satisfy the required anticommutation relation. However, they are not unique. Indeed, if $\gamma^\mu$ is one possible 4x4 set, and V is a 4x4 invertible matrix, then $\gamma'^\mu = V\gamma^\mu V^{-1}$ is also a possible set (i.e. it too will satisfy the anticommutation relation). This is trivial to prove, since $V^{-1}V
=1$.

Now I'm wondering if the converse is true: suppose I have two distinct sets of 4x4 matrices, $\gamma^\mu$ and $\gamma'^\mu$, which both satisfy the anticommutation requirement. Is it then true, that there exists an invertible 4x4 Matrix V, such that $\gamma'^\mu=V\gamma^\mu V^{-1}$? Is there a way to obtain an explicit expression for V in terms of $\gamma'^\mu$ and $\gamma^\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the content of Pauli's Lemma (1936). You can find a full answer here:

[Choice of Dirac gamma matrix representation and definition of adjoint spinor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390205/choice-of-dirac-gamma-matrix-representation-and-definition-of-adjoint-spinor?rq=1) and a proof of the lemma in Pauli's article:

Pauli,W. (1936), « *Contributions mathématiques à la théorie des matrices de Dirac* », in Annales de l'institut Henri Poincaré (Vol. 6, No. 2, pp. 109-136) (article freely available on the Numdam repository).

If you do not read French, then you can find an English proof in B. Thaller's "The Dirac Equation", Springer, 1992, p. 74.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!

Comment: I read the Pauli paper with great interest, but there are typos in the key step inthe english translation.  The text  says that if if $S= \sum_A {\gamma'}^a F\gamma^A$ is zero for *any* $F$ then $\sum_A( {\gamma'}^a)_{\sigma\tau} ({\gamma'}^A)_{\sigma'\tau'}=0$. The word *any* should be replaced by "*all*" and the last equation should be $\sum_A( {\gamma'}^a)_{\sigma\tau} ({\gamma}^A)_{\sigma'\tau'}=0$.  In other words   there should be no prime on the second gamma factor.

Comment: @mikestone Thanks for the comment, I know of it since like 2004, having read it in original paper form in the library of the KULeuven. As far as I still remember, Dirac's argument should be included in B. Thaller's "Dirac Equation" book. Anyways, there should be somewhere an English translation with no typos.

Comment: @DanielC  Thanks for the comment. I remember reading this Schur's lemma argument in Sylvan Schweber's book. I did not know that it was due to Pauli.  Schweber, I think, does not show that there is an $F$ for which $S$ is non-zero   and it took me ages to show that there had to be such an $F$.

Comment: @mikestone Not only that, but $S=\sum_A\gamma'^a F\gamma^A$ should be $S=\sum_A\gamma'^A F\gamma^A$: there is no index $a$ in the original French.